# Can I list a specific subgroup of "questions without upvoted answers"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Short description: I can't find a switch like "hasupvotedanswer:no" in [search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

I tried the search box but couldn't achieve the following (or any (other than the empty)) subset of "questions without upvoted answers": question with at least one upvote. I think this is a reasonable demand, because one could find more valuable questions in the unanswered list this way. Am I missing something or this is a missing feature?

Topics which should be included in the resultset:

- Question score is greater than zero **AND**
- There are no answers or all of them has lower score than 1 ("has no upvoted")
- Even if there's an [accepted answer with a score of 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139845/moving-contact-information-above-horizontal-line-in-resume/139983#139983)

Topics which should NOT be included:

- Question score is zero **OR**
- There is an upvoted answer

So I want to list questions without upvoted answers using a lower limit on the score ordered by submission time.

**Why** do I want to have such a functionality:

From time to time I tend to browse through "questions without upvoted answers". That's why I have Revival badges. I hope I'm not the only one who does this. However, this process could be more effective if I could easily focus on questions which are voted to be valuable by the community.

Comment: The filtering system is limited in terms of search across post types (questions and answers); it's easy to search *within* these types. For example, [searching for `score:1`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A1) yields *posts* (questions *or* answers) with a score of at least 1. Adding `is:question` filters for questions, while `is:answer` filters for answers, but not both. I guess for this to be a proper [meta-tag:feature-request], you should also include the value of adding such a feature. That is, what benefit would these search results reveal to the community?

Comment: @Werner: thanks for the tip (and the previous help, to make the question clear), I've just added what I had in mind.

Comment: if you go to the unanswered tab then you can order questions by votes, this doesn't filter the zero vote questions out but it does push them all to the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I would rather have them ordered by submission date, because I can keep my progress in mind that way (by bookmarking a question), with this ordering is not static but dynamic -- Update: this might be my best option (old question scores usually wouldn't fluctuate that much)

Comment: you need SO database SQL query thingy for this. I can't remember now. I'll paste if I remember it. But you don't need any subset. We already upvote almost all questions so it won't mean much had you had this functionality

Comment: @percusse I think you meant [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/new). ;) -- I'm still trying to get the hang of the join syntax here. -- and about the "upvoted almost everything" thing: then I would raise the limit to eg. 10

Comment: yea that one... but still you can sort the unanswered questions based on votes